# Shouldn't Hadoop group <key, (list of values) in reducer only based on hashCode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I decided to create my own WritableComparable class to learn how Hadoop works with it. So I create an Order class with two instance variables (orderNumber cliente) and implemented the required methods. I also used Eclipse generators for getters/setters/hashCode/equals/toString.

In compareTo, I've decided to use only the orderNumber variable.

I created a simple MapReduce job only to count the occurrences of an order in a dataset. By mistake one of my test records is Ita instead of Itá, as you can see here:

```
123 Ita
123 Itá
123 Itá
345 Carol
345 Carol
345 Carol
345 Carol
456 Iza Smith
```

As I understand the first record should be treated as a different order, because record 1 hashCode is de different from record 2 and 3 hashCodes.

But in reduce phase the 3 records are grouped together. As you can see here:

```
Order [cliente=Ita, orderNumber=123]    3
Order [cliente=Carol, orderNumber=345]  4
Order [cliente=Iza Smith, orderNumber=456]  1
```

I thought it should have a line for Itá records with count 2 and Ita should have count 1.

Well as I used only orderNumber in compareTo, I tried to use the String cliente in this method (commented on code below). And then, it worked as I was expecting.

So, is that an expected result? Shouldn't hadoop use only hashCode to group key and its values?

Here is the Order class (I ommited the getters/setters):

```
public class Order implements WritableComparable<Order>
{
private String cliente;
private long orderNumber;


@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException 
{
    cliente = in.readUTF();
    orderNumber = in.readLong();

}


@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException 
{
    out.writeUTF(cliente);
    out.writeLong(orderNumber);

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Order o) {
    long thisValue = this.orderNumber;
    long thatValue = o.orderNumber;
    return (thisValue < thatValue ? -1 :(thisValue == thatValue ? 0 :1));
    //return this.cliente.compareTo(o.cliente);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((cliente == null) ? 0 : cliente.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (int) (orderNumber ^ (orderNumber >>> 32));
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Order other = (Order) obj;
    if (cliente == null) {
        if (other.cliente != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!cliente.equals(other.cliente))
        return false;
    if (orderNumber != other.orderNumber)
        return false;
    return true;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Order [cliente=" + cliente + ", orderNumber=" + orderNumber + "]";
}
```

Here is the MapReduce code:

```
public class TesteCustomClass extends Configured implements Tool
{
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Order, LongWritable>
{
    LongWritable outputValue = new LongWritable();
    String[] campos;
    Order order = new Order();

        @Override
    public void configure(JobConf job)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Order, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
            {
        campos = value.toString().split("\t");

            order.setOrderNumber(Long.parseLong(campos[0]));
        order.setCliente(campos[1]);

        outputValue.set(1L);
        output.collect(order, outputValue);
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Order, LongWritable, Order,LongWritable>
{

    @Override
    public void reduce(Order key, Iterator<LongWritable> values,OutputCollector<Order,LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {
        LongWritable value = new LongWritable(0);
        while (values.hasNext())
        {
            value.set(value.get() + values.next().get());
        }
        output.collect(key, value);
    }
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(),TesteCustomClass.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    //  conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setJobName("Teste - Custom Classes");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Order.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));


    JobClient.runJob(conf);

    return 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(),new TesteCustomClass(),args);
    System.exit(res);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using a single reducer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default partitioner is the `HashPartitioner`, which uses the `hashCode` method to determine which reducer to send the K,V pair to.

Once in the reducer (or if you're using a Combiner which is run map side), the `compareTo` method is used to sort the keys and then also used (by default) to compare whether sequential keys should be grouped together and their associated values reduced in the same iteration.

If you don't use the `cliente` Key variable and only your `orderNumber` variable in your `compareTo` method, then any key with the same `orderNumber` will have its values reduced together - regardless of the `cliente` value (which is what you're currently observing)

Comment: Thank you Chris. Anyway, don't you think it would be better if the hashCode were used for grouping instead of compareTo?

Comment: HashPartitioner is only one partitioner available to hadoop, and using the compareTo method allows for secondary sorting in the reducer that enables other functionality